# Trying to convert Char String to integer output

Tags: java

Never Programmed before I have literally started this week trying to learn Java and I cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to take the value that is placed in the String digits variable and convert it into a Integer and return it to be output on the screen.  This is a custom package that I am writing for my testing software to be ale to use the char that I have read and placed into digits into a single number to place in a csv file.  I hope this made sense.

```
package custom;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConvertGetDigits {
    public Boolean executeCommand(String[] commandParameters, Properties scriptParameters) {
        if(commandParameters.length<1) {
            scriptParameters.put("Error", "Missing parameter in command. Usage: GetDigits CharsAndDigits");
            return false;
        }
        String text=commandParameters[0];
        String digits ="";
        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
            char c=text.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                digits+=c;
            }
        }   
        scriptParameters.put("Digits", digits);
        return true;
    }

    public String getTooltip() {
        return "Extracts all digits from a text as an Integer";
    }

    public String[] getParameters() {
        return new String[]{"Error", "Digits"};
    }

    public String getCommand() {
        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a text");
        if (text != null) {
            return "GetDigits " + text;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the question? Please simplify your code to focus on the problem only

Comment: I do not know how to simplify it.  I am trying to take what is returned into the String digits ="" and convert it to an Integer value and return the conversion as the output.  I hope that makes sense sorry.

Comment: So what is not working so far?

Comment: well i tried using int convertedDigits = Integer.valueOf(digits);

Comment: that seems to be good, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I tried adding another method to convert String Digits to an integer and return the value.  I think I have to declare a public sting at the beginning but confused.  Can I return both values or is there a way to convert the variable within the public boolean method.  Can I just create another Class and call the digits variable and convert it within the new class with a new method. ( Sorry for being a newbie).

Comment: first of all, you should check if the String is completley numeric, and then if it is just use `Integer.parseInt(yourStringGoesHere);` to convert it to an integer.